# free allocated memory when interoping c++

Tags: c#, c++, c, memory-management, pinvoke

populating an array of stuct containing string, i have tested an found out that in c# it performed faster via a pointer :

```
struct name{
    int intv;
    IntPtr strv;
}
```

when implementing via `GetPacksPtr()`:(see  code/signatures below)
that's how i code and not sure i am doing it right...

say ArrL=10,000

```
        DataPack* DataPackArr;
        List<DataPack> DataPackLst = new List<DataPack>(ArrL);
        GetPacksPtr(ArrL, &DataPackArr);

        DataPack* CurrentPack = DataPackArr;
        for (int i = 0; i < ArrL; i++, CurrentPack++)
        {
            DataPackLst.Add(new DataPack() { strv = CurrentPack->strv, intv = CurrentPack->intv });
        }
```

where can i free the memory allocated, as
`__stdcall` defines that the unmanaged code has to free the memory but who is the owner "by cotract"...it's confusing, i am trying to be responsible for freeing allocations **with minimum performance hit**.

**c++**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall GetPacksPtr(int size, DataPack** DpArrPtr )
{

    *DpArrPtr = (DataPack*)CoTaskMemAlloc( size * sizeof( DataPack ));
    DataPack CurPackPtr = *DpArrPtr;
    char aStr[]= "abcdefgHi";
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++,CurPackPtr++ )
    {

        CurPackPtr->IntVal=i;
        CurPackPtr->buffer = (char*)malloc(sizeof(aStr));
        strcpy(CurPackPtr->buffer, aStr);
    }


}
```

**c#**

```
    [DllImport("exported.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public static extern void GetPacksPtr(int RaySize, DataPack** DataPackArr);
```

Comment: If this is just c++ why did you tag [tag:c]? and why did you `extern "C"`? Do you understand what you're doing?

Comment: @iharob see Returning Strings from a C++ API to C# =>https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/returning-strings-from-a-c-api/

Comment: I don't mean that, I mean c is not c++, you are mixing things.

Comment: @iharob have a look at the examples at this link plz... i am learning too....

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is very common when you allocate memory manually and it's of course faster, you need another (this part I don't know what to say because you mixed everything) [c](/questions/tagged/c) function like this

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall FreePacksPtr(int size, DataPack *DpArrPtr)
{
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)
        free(DpArrPtr[i].buffer);
    CoTaskMemFree(DpArrPtr);
}
```

And then in your C# just call `FreePacksPtr()` whenever you don't need the pointer anymore.

**NOTE**: The fact that you need `extern "C"` means that the C# code is expecting to load the exact symbols from the dll, it seems like you have to instruct the microsoft compiler to compile c code instead of c++, I am not 100% sure but the microsoft compiler mixes these.

Comment: i am using  `extern "C"` cause that's the demo i just copy, but i did test cause i did question that too..but when removed: `Unable to find an entry point named 'GetPacksPtr' in DLL 'G:\....`

Comment: Yes which is what I am telling you. When a c++ program is compiled the symbols are changed so it can support overloading and that kind of things which I am not very familiar with. Perhaps all you need is to change the source files extensions to `.c`.

Comment: i guess this is kind'a trick if i am right, that writing cpp, by stating extern C it compiles a cDll that's why i get the performance gain... i wonder...

Comment: as for the story of memory managment, and in general, thank you for a good answer and code solution.

Comment: still thinking of it trying to make a decision on a strategy to free memory without carrying it "till the end" because of what you said, but also not doing it when you need work to be done, like in a dead spot like a background operation without hurting the performance, somewhere where the program is idle.

Answer (score 2):

When you allocate unmanaged memory you have to free it - but there are no rules about who is responsible for freeing.

In the unmanaged world it's a common tactic to have an "owner" for each resource that needs freeing, this ownership is the responsibility for freeing the object.

If function A allocates a block of memory and then pass a pointer to function B there are two options:

1. A remains the owner and will free the memory when done, B doesn't have to deal with freeing the memory but also can't save the pointer for later because it can get freed at any time by A
2. The ownership is transferred from A to B, now B is responsible for freeing and A can't do anything with the pointer after B returns because it could be freed at any time by B

Note that there is nothing in the function prototype that represents ownership this is all by agreement between the programmer writing A and the programmer writing B (and is often referred to as "by contract")

Now, to make things more complicated there are many blocks of memory you can allocate from (called "heaps") and when you free you need to free into the same heap you used for allocating.

There are several heaps managed by Windows and the .net Marshal class have methods for freeing memory into them.

The heap used by malloc is not one of them, memory allocated by malloc must be freed by calling free in the same dll that called malloc.

And, last but not least, allocating and freeing memory is one of the slowest things you can do in unmanaged code and if you do that a lot you get into trouble with things like memory fragmentation and locality of reference (this answer is long enough without getting into them)

Allocating and freeing strategies have a huge impact on the performance of unmanaged code - this will not have minimal impact on your performance.

Comment: but as you can see, nir, @ iharob gave a solution in his code (extra call, extra cpu time) though **only** while i end the usage for me it could accure at the end of the section of the program, and using maloc and interop to the dll instead of managed did some performance gain by a factor of **x8** in comparison to the managed alternative List<whatEverUChoose> to popultae.

Comment: so it means that i should just make sure i do not cause any heap fragmentation ... i will see to that issue, try to learn how it could be avoided. thanks for that remark and in general for your information !

Comment: @RajFelix - using unmanaged memory can be faster - but you have to measure the real effect on the app and not a micro-benchmark, for example, if you free only at the end your app now uses more memory, using memory increase the chance the OS will have to swap out some of it to disk and going to disk is so slow this will be much slower then using managed memory

Comment: it is quite a 'project' (looking into the de-fragmatation solutions) i will continue when my program will grow so i could get more parameters to punch in ...(:

Comment: @RajFelix - unmanaged memory allocation is complicated, I'm not saying "don't do it" but I am saying "proceed with caution" - and that, performance wise, what works in a small test project does not work the same in a big application. until you measure performance in the real full app you don't know anything